# Why are spatial derivatives of a field not used to define the conjugate momentum?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, momentum, field-theory, time, hamiltonian-formalism

In mechanics, the conjugate momentum is defined to be $\pi=\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)}.$ This can be regarded as a partial derivative with respect to a derivative of a dependent variable ($x$ depends on $t$, the latter being the independent variable). In (scalar) field theory, the number of independent variables increases: $\phi$ depends on $\{t,x,\cdots\}$. One may hence define multiple quantities: $$\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}\right)},\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\right)},\cdots.$$ And yet, only the first quantity is regarded as the conjugate momentum and in canonical quantization scheme, is used to obtain the "equal **time**" commutation relations. Why don't we use the remaining quantities? Is it because $\{x,\cdots\}$ are still regarded as dependent variables (not on the same footing with $t$)? What is going on from a purely mathematical point of view?

Comment: I shall read about covariant quantization. However, I am not sure why the Hamiltonian should not be Lorentz invariant.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38286/2451, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144410/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

The Hamiltonian formulation explicitily breaks Lorentz by choosing a particular direction in spacetime, namely $t$. More generally, one can foliate spacetime with spacetime surfaces $\Sigma_t$, where $t$ denotes a coordinate along a congruence, which can be thought as a time coordinate. This construction is used in Hamiltonian formulation of GR, which is known as **ADM Formalism** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism.

There is some research of defining this construction without breaking general covariance, you may find this paper by D.Harlow useful https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.08616.