# Quantization surface in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, hamiltonian-formalism, quantization, causality

[image]

What does the Quantization Surface mean here?

Reference: H. Latal W. Schweiger (Eds.) - Methods of Quantization

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The word *quantization surface* is not  standard terminology. It apparently refer to a (generalized) [Cauchy surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_surface). A (generalized) Cauchy surface is a [hypersurface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersurface) on which the initial conditions are given for a well-posed [initial value problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem). Phrased differently, for given initial conditions on the Cauchy surface, there exists a unique solution for the evolution differential equation in an appropriate bulk region. (For more information, see also [hyperbolic PDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_partial_differential_equation) and [causal structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure) on Wikipedia.)

Here the *evolution parameter* of the system is usually referred to as *time,* although it doesn't have to be actual time. It could also be [light cone time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone_coordinates) $x^{+}$, etc. Similarly, the word *initial* does not need to refer to actual time.

The *evolution differential equation* could be e.g. the [Schrödinger equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation), the [Klein-Gordon equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation), the [Maxwell's equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations), the [Navier-Stokes equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations), the [Einstein field equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations), the [Arnowitt-Deser-Misner (ADM) equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism) of GR, etc.

In the context of [quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_quantization) of a classical field theory, it is usually meant that the evolution problem is given in Hamiltonian form. Traditional Hamiltonian formulation (as opposed to manifestly covariant$^1$ Hamiltonian formulation) has a distinguished spacetime coordinate, which then plays the role of evolution parameter.

--

$^1$ There are various manifestly covariant Hamiltonian formalisms. See e.g. [De Donder-Weyl theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Donder%E2%80%93Weyl_theory); [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26883/2451) Phys.SE post; and the following reference: C. Crnkovic and E. Witten, *Covariant description of canonical formalism in geometrical theories.* Published in *Three hundred years of gravitation* (Eds. S. W. Hawking and W. Israel), (1987) 676.