# What will happen if one used $[\phi (x), \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial _x\phi(x))}]=i\hbar$ to get a Quantum Field Theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, spacetime, time, classical-field-theory

Classical field theory does not discriminate between space and time, but canonical quantisation does. We use the relation $$[\phi (x), \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial _t\phi(x))}]=i\hbar$$ to get the quantum theory. What if we instead used $$[\phi (x), \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial _x\phi(x))}]=i\hbar~?$$

In this, the canonical momentum has a $\partial_ x$ instead of $\partial _t$. I know this would give us a bad a theory which would not agree with experiments, but **is there a mathematical motivation to disregard this**? Why does nature prefer to implement probabilities in the time direction? Could this also be the reason consciousness perceives the universe in the time direction?

**EDIT** One thing I found is that we would need to deal with inverted harmonic oscillators if we tried this weird quantisation. This is because the new mode expansion of the field is:

$$\sum_{p_0,p_2,p_3} ae^{-i (\omega x+p_0t+p_2y+p_3z)} + a^{\dagger}e^{i (\omega x+p_0t+p_2y+p_3z)},$$

where $\omega = \sqrt {p_0^2-p_2^2-p_3^2}$. So we need to constrain the value of $(p_0,p_2,p_3)$ to not end up with imaginary $\omega$ values. If we don't constrain them, then we get imaginary frequencies which, when quantised, will result in Quantum **Inverted** Harmonic Oscillators.

From what I've found about Inverted Quantum Oscillators, they have difficulties with a probabilistic interpretation. Is this enough of a mathematical reason to discard this quantisation? Did nature choose the time direction to implement probabilities because this is the **only direction** where probabilities can be implemented? The time direction differs from the other directions in the **metric sign**.

In the case of Euclidean spacetime, we end up with $\omega =\sqrt {-p_1^2-p_2^2-p_3^2}$. Now there is no way to avoid imaginary $\omega$ **even with constraints**. Could this be used to mathematically motivate why nature chose Minkowski spacetime?

Answer (score 2):

1. Conventionally, we assume there exists an initial/[Cauchy surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_surface) $\Sigma$ of co-dimension$^1$ 1 in spacetime, and that the fields satisfy a [hyperbolic PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_partial_differential_equation). The [CCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) arises from the [symplectic structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_geometry) on $\Sigma$, cf. my Phys.SE answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/77706/2451) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/38337/2451).
2. OP's title qustion is ruled out because the corresponding Cauchy surface would have timelike directions.
3. Similarly, spacetimes with Euclidean signature are ruled out because they corresponds to an [elliptic PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_partial_differential_equation).

--

$^1$This is related to that spacetime is a [Lorentzian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold#Lorentzian_manifold). For theories with multiple temporal dimensions, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43322/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: But this doesn't explain why we conventionally assume these things.

Comment: @RyderRude But you didn't ask why we conventionally assume these things. You asked "[w]hat will happen if one used  [ϕ(x),∂L∂(∂xϕ(x))]=iℏ  to get a Quantum Field Theory?"  And you asked "is there a mathematical motivation to disregard this?" Did this answer answer the questions you actually asked?