Canonical commutation relations of quantum fields in null coordinates
To quantize a scalar field, we impose the equal time commutation relations
$$
[\Phi(t,\mathbf{x}),\partial_t\Phi(t,\mathbf{x}')] = i\hbar\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{x-x'}).
$$
This can also be generalized to spacetimes which are not flat by choosing a spacelike slicing.
Now as per equation 2.13 in this paper, the canonical commutation relations for a flat background in null coordinates $U = t-x,V=t+x$ read:
$$
[\Phi(U_1,V,\zeta_1),\partial_U\Phi(U_2,V,\zeta_2)] = \frac{i\hbar}{2}\delta(U_1 - U_2)\delta^{(d-1)}(\mathbf{\zeta_1-\zeta_2})\tag{ 2.13}
$$
Where $\zeta$ represents transverse coordinates. I understand this as follows:
I write the lagrangian in  null coordinates,
$$
\mathcal{L} = 2\partial_U\Phi\partial_V\Phi + ... 
$$
If I take the $V$ coordinate as time, then the conjugate momentum should be
$$
\Pi = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_V\Phi)} = 2\partial_U\Phi
$$
Which gives me the canonical commutation relation for equal $V$ as written above. However there are two things that I do not understand about this:

How is it justified to take $V$ as the time coordinate-- since it is null and $V = constt.$ is not a spacelike but null hypersurface.

Since it is the same theory we are quantizing in two different coordinate systems, the two commutation relations must be equivalent. Is there some way to explicitly see that?



Non-timelike parametrization can sometimes be helpful in describing evolution of a physical system in certain kinematic sectors. Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77700/2451

It is possible to write the CCR without reference to a coordinate system, by using the "commutator function", ou Pauli-Jordan propagator. This is the advanced Green's function minus the retarded Green's function. 1401.2026 writes this in p. 11 (but I think there is a sign mistake in the definition of the commutator $E$, which inverts the usual CCR)

I think 1506.01869 has a nice discussion of the commutator function. Maybe playing around with these ideas can help you in getting from one expression of the CCR to the other
