# Hamiltonian formalism (with symplectic form) for time-dependent Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, canonical-conjugation

I have been working on some results that work for time-independent Lagrangians $L\Big(q,\dot{q}\Big)$ and return a Hamiltonian function

$$
H(q,\dot{q})=\dot{q}^i \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i}-L
$$

and a symplectic form

$$
\Omega=\delta \Big(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i }\Big)\wedge \delta  q^i 
$$

where the idea is that we can read off the canonical momentum $p_i=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i}$ from the symplectic form.

When the Lagrangian has an explicit time dependence $L\Big(t,q,\dot{q}\Big)$, I'm not sure how this works. What I tried to do was to treat $t$ as a new coordinate and define $q^\mu=(t,q^i)$ and parametrize everything with some new parameter $s$ such that

\begin{align}
S[q]&=\int dt L\Big(t,q(t),\dot{q}(t)\Big)\\
&=\int ds\  \frac{dt}{ds} L\Big(t(s),q(s),\big(\frac{dt}{ds}\big)^{-1} q'(s)\Big)
&= \int ds \tilde{L}(q^\mu,q'^\mu)
\end{align}
where we defined $q'=\frac{dq}{ds}$ as opposed to $\dot{q}=\frac{dq}{dt}$. The problem with this new Lagrangian is that the Legendre transformation vanishes identically. Indeed

\begin{align}
\tilde{H}&=q'^\mu  \frac{\partial \tilde{L}}{\partial q'^\mu}-\tilde{L}\\
&=0
\end{align}
Instead, the Hamiltonian is simply the canonical momentum conjugate to $t$

\begin{align}
H(t,q^i,\dot{q}^i)&=-\frac{\partial \tilde{L}}{\partial t'}\\
&=\dot{q}^i \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i}-L(t,q^i,\dot{q}^i)
\end{align}

**My question is: In this framework where we treat $t$ as a new coordinate and parametrize it with a new time $s$, how do we calculate the symplectic form for $H$?**

Answer (score 1):

- OP's question seems to be partly inspired by the covariant Hamiltonian/phase space formalism, cf. e.g. OP's previous question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/789261/2451).
- OP's method of generating a worldline (WL) reparametrization invariant formulation is also considered in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/807317/2451), which is summarized below.

1. Let us first consider the Lagrangian formalism. Given a possibly time-dependent Lagrangian $L(t,q,v)$, define a WL reparametrization invariant action
   $$\begin{align}\widetilde{S}[t,q]~=~&\int\! ds~\widetilde{L}(t,q,\dot{q}), \cr \widetilde{L}(t,q,\dot{t},\dot{q})~:=~&\dot{t}L(t,q,\frac{\dot{q}}{\dot{t}}),\end{align} \tag{A}$$
   where dot denotes differentiation wrt. $s$. The corresponding symplectic form is defined as
   $$ \widetilde{\Omega}~:=~\delta \Big(\frac{\partial \widetilde{L}}{\partial \dot{t} }\Big)\wedge \delta t +\delta \Big(\frac{\partial \widetilde{L}}{\partial \dot{q}^j }\Big)\wedge \delta  q^j,\tag{B} $$
   cf. OP's question.
2. Next let us consider the Hamiltonian formalism. Given a possibly time-dependent Hamiltonian Lagrangian $$L_H(t,q,p,v)~=~p_jv^j-H(t,q,p), \tag{C}$$
   define a worldline (WL) reparametrization invariant Hamiltonian action
   $$\begin{align}\widetilde{S}_H[t,q,p_t,p,e]~=~&\int\! ds~\widetilde{L}_H(t,q,\dot{t},\dot{q},p_t,p,e), \cr 
   \widetilde{L}_H(t,q,\dot{t},\dot{q},p_t,p,e)~:=~&p_j\dot{q}^j+p_t\dot{t}-\widetilde{H}(t,q,p_t,p,e),\cr\widetilde{H}(t,q,p_t,p,e)~:=~&e(p_t+H(t,q,p)),
   \end{align} \tag{D}$$
   where the einbein field $e$ is a [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). The corresponding symplectic form is defined as
   $$ \widetilde{\Omega}_H~:=~\delta p_t\wedge \delta t +\delta p_j\wedge \delta  q^j,\tag{E} $$
   cf. OP's question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There's one thing I don't understand. What Hamiltonian function are you using to get Hamilton's equations? If we define a variable $Q^A=(t,q^j,p_t,p_j)$ are they still $\frac{dQ^A}{ds}=\Omega^{AB}H_{,B}$? Which $H$ goes there? The one that vanishes identically? Or just the one that is defined as the canonical momentum conjugated to t?

Comment: I updated the answer.