# In a classical scalar field theory, is the Hamiltonian Lorentz-invariant? How about the Lagrangian?

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, covariance

I encountered a statement that "while Lorentz invariance is apparent in the Lagrangian formulation, it is not so in the Hamiltonian formulation of a classical field." I do not completely understand this statement, though I thought this statement was essentially pointing to the two questions I asked.

Comment: Since this question is about *appearances*, it would be clearer if you *showed* the Lagrangian and the Hamiltonian for a relativistic scalar field.

Comment: Here is a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that you can write them.

Answer (score 3):

More generally (not just for scalar field theory), the main points are:

- The Lagrangian formulation of a relativistic$^1$ field theory is manifestly Lorentz-covariant as it is constructed from manifestly Lorentz-covariant objects.
- Therefore the corresponding Hamiltonian formalism, defined via a Legendre transform, must in principle also be Lorentz-covariant, as the two formalisms describe the same underlying theory. However, such Hamiltonian formalism is not manifestly Lorentz-covariant as it singles out the time-coordinate.
- Concerning a manifestly covariant Hamiltonian formalism, see e.g. Ref. 1 and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26883/2451) Phys.SE post.

References:

1. C. Crnkovic and E. Witten, *Covariant description of canonical formalism in geometrical theories.* Published in *Three hundred years of gravitation* (Eds. S. W. Hawking and W. Israel), (1987) 676.

--

$^1$ The Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formulations of non-relativistic theories are not Lorentz-covariant (and we shall not discuss them further).